# How can I achieve local caching using Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, google-cloud-platform, redis, spring-cache

I am trying to setup a spring boot application and looking for options to store the small data in the local cache and then this local cache interacts with Redis server which will be on google cloud platform. This local cache can be shared across multiple nodes. I see Redis pro can help to achieve this but that is not free. Is there any open source option I can use? Or any other way I can set this up in Spring boot? How can I set this local cache which syncs up with the central cache? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redisson https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/14.-Integration-with-frameworks/#1421-spring-cache-local-cache-and-data-partitioning. It's available in the Pro version.

If you would like to implement it by yourself, you would need to implement custom `CacheManager` that first looks up entries in local cache (implemented likely with something smarter than a `HashMap`, like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), if entry not found goes to Redis based `CacheManager` and then depending on the result puts the data to Caffeine cache.

For storing data in Redis and making sure all nodes are in sync, you can use [Redis Pub/Sub](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/redis-getting-notified-when-a-key-is-expired-or-changed-ca3e1f1c7f0a) mechanism to notify each connected node to update local cache.

Comment: Thanks bro that really put me in the correct direction.  Redission pro is not open source right? Is there any alternative I can use similar like pro which is not paid and is open source?

Comment: I'm not aware of any open source option. You would have to implement it yourself :-)

Comment: Now I realised that Redis 6 includes client side caching - perhaps another option that is simpler than what I came up with based on Redis < 6 experience https://redis.io/topics/client-side-caching

Comment: This is great to achieve the local caching mechanism.. Basically this is how am looking to implement like App -> local cache -> nodes -> redis instance/server so i guess still have to use pub/sub to sync up with all nodes and then with the redis instance?

Comment: I would have to dig into this local cache topic, that I have no time for at the moment. Post here your solution once you figure it out

Comment: I found one great article which basically explains well with two level caching, i will trying this for now  - https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/implementation-of-two-level-cache-with-springboot-springcache-redis-caffeine.html

Answer (score 0):

***[Spring Boot for Apache Geode](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode#spring-boot-for-apache-geode)*** (SBDG) offers client-side caching, or what is commonly referred to as "*Near Caching*".  See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider-near-caching).

HISTORY

***[Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/)*** is an open source software (OSS), *In-Memory Data Grid* (IMDG) technology, having an Apache 2 License. Indeed, it can be much more than a cache if need be, but fits perfectly well in the caching use case, at any layer in the application architecture (Web, Service, Data).

The commercial version of ***Apache Geode*** is ***[VMware Tanzu GemFire](https://tanzu.vmware.com/gemfire)***, built on ***Apache Geode*** source with support from [VMware](https://tanzu.vmware.com/), if needed. But, to use ***Apache Geode***, is completely free.

In fact, the original [Spring Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) was inspired by **Costin Leau's** development (original lead & creator) of [Spring Data GemFire](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-gemfire), which has been replaced by [Spring Data for Apache Geode](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-geode) (SDG), to focus on the OSS offering. (See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:spring-cache-abstraction)/[alt-here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-caching), then [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-store-configuration), as well as [from Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.caching.provider)).

SBDG is an extension of SDG to give users of ***Apache Geode*** (or alternatively, VMware Tanzu GemFire) a proper and first-class experience using ***Apache Geode*** in a *Spring* context, and specifically with *Spring Boot* features (e.g. auto-configuration). That is, SBDG is a special extension of *Spring Boot* catered specifically to *Apache Geode* to handle a variety of application concerns (like caching) that is owned and maintained by the *Spring Team*, itself.

SBDG is even capable of handling [several caching patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider-look-aside-near-inline-multi-site) in addition to "*Near Caching*". See the [topic of caching in general](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider).

Finally, SBDG also includes ***[Spring Session for Apache Geode](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-data-geode)*** (SSDG) to handle your Web, HTTP Session state caching concerns independent of you Web container (e.g. Tomcat) using ***Apache Geode*** as the *caching provider* for the HTTP Session state. It is, of course, built on *Spring Session* core (see [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-core)).

Comment: NOTE: The only annotation you might want to use for convenience (is SDG's `@EnableCachingDefinedRegions` annotation which creates Spring `Caches` (backed by *Apache Geode* cache `Region`s) from the cache names declared in the Spring or JSR-107 Caching annotations (e.g. `@Cacheable`).  SBDG automatically configures *Apache Geode* as a *caching provider* when on the application CLASSPATH, which eliminates the explicit need to declare Spring's `@EnableCaching` (or alternatively, SDG's `@EnableGemfireCaching`) annotation and an explicit `CacheManager`.

Comment: NOTE: When configuring and using SBDG's ***Near Caching*** capabilities, there is no extra logic required by your application.  *Apache Geode* is automatically handling the interactions between the client-side cache Region and server-side cache Region.  The only thing you may want to do is tune your "interests registrations", particle if you have a distributed application with multiple instances using and updating the cache.

Comment: NOTE: It is also possible to start in a completely "local-only" arrangement (i.e. using a client-side cache only) and later switch to a client/server topology as necessary, which can help users ease into caching, and *Apache Geode*, in particular.

Comment: NOTE: Finally, see the samples, which includes examples for all the *caching patterns* and *use cases* (e.g. HTTP Session state caching with *Spring Session*): https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-samples

Comment: Thank you all for your great responses and it is very helpful. I also found one great article on caffeine and redis implementation with spring boot app here it is -> https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/implementation-of-two-level-cache-with-springboot-springcache-redis-caffeine.html

Comment: Additionally, can I use ehcache as local and redis as remote? Is that even possible? If yes is there any sample integration? Trying to find but could not find it :(

Comment: Not out of the box from *Spring* or *Spring Boot*, anyway.  You would have to implement your own custom solution (with a custom `CacheManager` and `Cache` implementation) based on this combination of the existing *caching providers* (e.g. Ehcache & Redis) if they don't offer such an integration, already.

Comment: I would recommend using a caching provider that offers such a solution already, and fallback to implementing your own if you are required to use a certain caching provider or combination of providers that don't already offer this capability out of the box.